# Не удаётся выполнить vk api запрос из node js

Tags: node.js, vkontakte-api

Для работы с vk api выбрал vksdk пакет(модуль). Вот ссылка на пакет https://www.npmjs.com/package/vksdk

Я пытаюсь создать пост в группе через запрос, однако, ничего не получается, никакого поста в группе не создается. У меня зарегистрировано как Standalone приложение и Токен у меня создан для сообщества(Implicit flow).

Подскажите пожалуйста, я не правильно использую функциональность пакета или не правильно зарегистрировал приложение(может токен не тот создан)?

```js
var VK = require("vksdk");

var vk = new VK({
    'appSecret' : 6693739,
    'appId'     : 'VtfrleQIkcIxFOK13IAw',
    'language'  : 'ru'
});

vk.setToken('****');
//vk.setSecureRequests(true);

vk.request('wall.post', {
    'owner_id' : -111,
    'friends_only' : 0,
    'from_group' : 1,
    'message' : 'Hello World!'
}, function(foo){
    console.log('Request WALL.POST: '+ foo + '\n');
})
```

Comment: А какой результат/ошибка выходит?

Comment: @Let's say Pie Нет, никакой ошибки не выдает....через try catch тоже ничего

Comment: @Z.Vladimir вы там лимиты не превысили? У них ограничение на количество запросов в секунду.

Comment: @Suvitruf я новичок в этой теме(node js and vk api), но все же с программированием не первый раз столкнулся и я не могу увидеть намек на то что я отправляю запрос многократно, если это возможно исходя из моего текущего кода - подскажите пожалуйста. Исходя из вашего вопроса я решил поэкспериментировать и запихнул запрос в таймер, но результат все тот же - ничего...

Answer (score 0):

Я вот смотрю код либы, и вижу, что оно [не всегда возвращает ответ в колбеке](https://github.com/57uff3r/nodejs-vksdk/blob/master/sdk.js#L312).

Перед вызовом `vk.request` напишите:

```
vk.on('http-error', function(_e) {
    console.log("http-error: %o",_e);
});
```

Почти 100% гарантия, что тут ошибка выведется.

Ну и заодно на `parse-error`:

```
vk.on('parse-error', function(_e) {
    console.log("parse-error: %o",_e);
});
```

Comment: да, так и есть, вывело ошибку http-error "connect ETIMEDOUT 87.240.129.75:443"

Comment: @Z.Vladimir у вас там на машине вообще выход в интернет есть? Если да, то попробуйте к этому ip обратиться curl'ом. Если и он по таймауту отвалится, значит просто недоступен этот ip, и проблема ничего общего с библиотекой не имеет.

Comment: c ip оказались проблемы...есть проблема, я нашел в пакете vksdk файл sdk.js и там поменял порт, а вот ip где - не нашел

Comment: @Z.Vladimir ip резолвится из домена DNS сервером.

Comment: ага, я вроде начинаю вникать....смотрите по умолчанию стоял ip 87.240.129.75(api.vk.com) и я ж поменял его на такой же как и у моего сайта 127.0.0.1, верно ж сделал? но теперь он выдает ошибку "socket hang up"

Comment: @Z.Vladimir эээм. Нет, ip там правильный был...